# vuejs expression that has an or operator to check if property is found

Tags: vue.js

I am using vuejs and I have an expression where I want to check to see if the name comes from either FilterName or FilterName2 by using the expression only. I do not want to use a computed property. Is there a way to write this with just expression

```js
 
 new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   FilteredName:""
   FilteredName2:"XX_110_OY_M10"

  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<p>

 {{FilteredName || FilteredName2 + "_" + "_DEVELOPMENT" }}
 
 </p>
 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Nullish Coalescing Operator vs OR Operator

If one of them is guaranteed to be `null`, `undefined`, `0` or an empty string (`""`), then `||` operator would work exactly the same way as the Nullish coalescing operator in your case.

The OR `||` Operator is better to use in your case since it works the same (for this case) and has [better support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing) than nullish coalescing, due to the latter being released in 2020, so older browsers do not support it.

You just have to use it with brackets for clarity:

```
{{ (FilteredName || FilteredName2) + "_" + "_DEVELOPMENT" }}
```

The important difference between them is that:

> `||` returns the first **truthy** value.

> `??` returns the first **defined** value.

**Read more:** https://javascript.info/nullish-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 0):

If either of them are guaranteed to be null, I'd use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```
(FilteredName ?? FilteredName2) + "_" + "_DEVELOPMENT"
```